# Possible solutions for a SQLNonTransientException

Tags: java, db2, database-connection

I am very new to database connections with Java and am having a difficult time connecting to the database I was provided. So far I've learned that installing the correct DB2 drivers may have been an issue and putting them in the `CLASSPATH` for the program. I have done this and I still am not able to establish a connection. Please Help!

Here is a print out of my error report in Eclipse:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlNonTransientConnectionException:
>   [jcc][t4][10380][11951][4.13.127] Required property "URLname" is
>   unknown host. ERRORCODE=-4222, SQLSTATE=08001     at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:667)  at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:60)   at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.id.a(id.java:103)  at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.(a.java:231)   at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.a(b.java:1901)   at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kb.a(kb.java:700)  at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.kb.(kb.java:653)     at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b.(b.java:332)   at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:231)
>     at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource.getConnection(DB2SimpleDataSource.java:197)
>     at com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:472)    at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver.connect(DB2Driver.java:113)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   ServerAcessDemo.main(ServerAcessDemo.java:23)

Here is the code I have developed so far:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class ServerAcessDemo{

    // jdbc driver name and database URL
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:db2://URLname/portNumber";

    // Database credentials
    static final String USER = "userID";
    static final String PASSWORD = "password";

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Connection conn = null;
        try{
            // Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);

            // open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASSWORD);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            // handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            // finally block used to close resources
            try{
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
        }//end try
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is as simple as that, but you set:

```
static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:db2://URLname/portNumber";
```

and the error is `Required property "URLname" is unknown host`, so it seems that you have supplied wrong DB_URL value, it should be something like `jdbc:db2://localhost:50000/your_database_name`, assuming your DB runs locally on 50000 port, you need to provide right database name.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out. It was a syntax error in my database name URL. I put the forward slash in stead of a colon before the port #. It's always the small things. Thank you.